# Surface - dequeueBuffer failed (Unknown error 2147483646)

Tags: android, webview

I've been struggling for 3 days with an android app that uses a `webview` to load my website that contains thousands of images.
The application start well but after scrolling trough a couple hundred images the `webview` freezes (it doesn't force-close) the [logcat (check it on pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/X7mLrZnv) shows

```
E/Surface dequeueBuffer failed (Unknown error 2147483646)
```

What I've tried:

1. Limit the number of images on every activity, when a user views 100
   images, start another activity.
2. Clear the webview cache onCreation, onPause, onStop, etc...
   `clearCache(true);`
3. Set the webview cache to false `setAppCacheEnabled(false);`
4. Kill activity A after opening activity B and vice versa
5. Set the `webView.setLayerType()` to NONE, SOFTWARE and HARDWARE
6. Declare `"android:largeHeap="true"` and
   `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` on the manifest.
7. Put the webview inside a placeholder a remove it before `finish();`

---

```
webViewPlaceholder.removeView(myWebView);  
myWebView.removeAllViews();  
myWebView.destroy();
```

It seems that android keeps the `webview` in memory and cleaning the cache doesn't have any effect.
When I close the app and reopen it the error appears immediately, so it seems that not even closing the app releases the memory it uses.
I've read a fair amount of answers at SO regarding `webview` problems , but I still couldn't fix the problem and any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I am also having similar problems. Can you help if you were able to fix this problem?

Comment: @isa This question is 8 years old and I honestly don't remember the context or  project and if I actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

for KitKat 4.4.3 or later set the hardware acceleration to false:

```
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```